Why can I not upgrade sysv-rc-conf on Debian as it's held back? (is there an alternative tool)
Why was sysv-rc-conf removed from the Debian repos? Is there for example a better alternative with a GUI?
When I run sudo apt-get upgrade it's the only package held back:
The following packages have been kept back:
  sysv-rc-conf

When I run sudo sysv-rc-conf I can still configure autostarting services in the console. I find it difficult to use as it's not a GUI and has just unexplained numbers as columns. Nevertheless, instead of removing I'd like to install some substitution tool that can also configure autostarting services.
Description: SysV init runlevel configuration tool for the terminal
 sysv-rc-conf provides a terminal GUI for managing "/etc/rc{runlevel}.d/"
 symlinks.  The interface comes in two different flavors, one that simply
 allows turning services on or off and another that allows for more fine tuned
 management of the symlinks.  Unlike most runlevel config programs, you can
 edit startup scripts for any runlevel, not just your current one.

It probably has something to do with "orphan-sysvinit-scripts" showing up in KDE Discover and Apper to be installed (but getting installed or upgraded when upgrading).

stupid question: KDE with sysV init, is that even a sensible option? doesn't KDE inherently depend on things like xdg-portals, socket-activated units, pipewire, user sessions, cgroups scopes, … i.e., all things that sysv init has absolutely no provisions for and that you'd want to use a manager like systemd for, anyways? If that's the case, why do you have old-OLD-style sysv-rc config tooling? It's not like you will travel back in time to get an rc.d script that needs to be mapped to a new-style init script that then will probably just be mapped to systemd?That makes very little sense to me!

Isn't Debian completely in on systemd? Why would it keep a script for sysv init around?

@muru it’s still possible to set Debian up with other init systems, in some scenarios; apparently that includes systems with KDE. (GNOME requires systemd.)

sysv-rc-conf hasn’t been removed, it’s been changed to only be installable on systems actually using sysvinit. Since your system apparently isn’t, you can’t upgrade the package and it is automatically held back; if you want to use systemd, you should remove it.
systemd used to provide a UI, systemd-ui, but that’s been abandoned for a long time. KDE has its own systemd configuration tool, systemdgenie, but that doesn’t seem to be packaged in Debian (you discovered that previously).
Technically it seems that KDE can be used with sysvinit-core on Debian; you could try installing that (which will remove the systemd package).

I wonder why it shows things when the system is not actually using SysV. So if I understood correctly it's useless and things I configure with this tool would not have any effect since I'm using systemd which I don't intend to change. Heard Devuan users have an issue with systemd but don't yet really see their point. If deciding to use SysV I guess it would be better to use Devuan. Somebody needs to salvage systemdgenie. I'll just sudo apt-get remove sysv-rc-conf then. btw after removing "orphan-sysvinit-scripts" is not showing up in Apper anymore.

A number of packages still ship sysvinit scripts, and sysv-rc-conf shows those. They are transparently handled by systemd, so they still work, but I’m not sure what effect changing the settings in sysv-rc-conf would have.

Regarding systemdgenie, it would be useful if you could file a package request bug — reportbug wnpp and follow the prompts for an “RFP” (there isn’t one yet).
